# Prove $\int_{a}^{b} \,d\alpha = \alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

> Prove directly from the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral that $\int_{a}^{b} \,d\alpha = \alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$

Here is my attempt:

Assuming that it exists, by definition, we have $\int_{a}^b \,d\alpha=\overline{\int_{a}^b} \,d\alpha=\text{inf }U(P)=\text{inf }\sum_{i=1}^n M_i\Delta \alpha_i$. Since $f(x)=1$ everywhere, $M_i=1$ independent from any partition $P$. So, $\text{inf }\sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta \alpha_i=\text{inf }\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta\alpha_i=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$.

Is this proof ok? Also, I'm not sure if I should say anything about the existence of its Riemann-Stieltjes integral for this question. If yes, then I'd use the fact that $f(x)=1$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, so Theorem 6.8 of baby Rudin, i.e. if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f\in \mathcal{R}_\alpha[a,b]$, ensures its existence. But my concern is that I do not prove the existence directly from the definition.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to justify the very last equality. What happens to the sum? What happens to the $\inf$? The reasoning here is what will establish existence of the integral.

Comment: @Karl What do you mean? I just think $\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta \alpha_i$ is just a sum of all subintervals, so $\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta \alpha_i=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$, and this is true for whatever partition you choose, right?

Comment: Yeah, so you're taking the infimum of a singleton set; the supremum will be the same. (I'm assuming your definitions imply that the integral exists if the inf and sup are equal.)

Comment: Ah right, thanks

Comment: Are you given that $\alpha$ is monotone?  If not, then the upper /lower integral concept does not apply.

Comment: Further, appealing to the existence theorem for continuous functions is somewhat of an overkill. Everything follows from definition.

Answer (score 3):

With $f(x) \equiv 1$ ,  a Riemann-Stieltjes sum corresponding to an arbitrary  partion $P=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and any choice of tags $\xi_j \in [x_{j-1},x_j]$ is given by

$$S(P,f,\alpha,\{\xi_j\}) = \sum_{j=1}^n f(\xi_j)[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})]= \sum_{j=1}^n [\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})]= \alpha(b) - \alpha(a).$$

Consequently, we see both that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral exists and takes the value $\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)$, since

$$\Delta := \left|S(P,f,\alpha,\{\xi_j\})- [\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)]\right|= 0,$$

and, consequently, for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$ (any choice will do) with the property that for any refinement $P \supset P_\epsilon$ and any choice of tags $\{\xi_j\}$ we have  $\Delta < \epsilon$.

By arguing directly from the definition in this way, we can prove the result without assuming that the integrator $\alpha$ is monotone and appealing to the notion of upper and lower Darboux integrals.